# Elasticsearch how to exclude some fields in indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a JSON data that maps automatically by the elastic search when I'm indexing the data. How can I exclude some fields in the mapping. I already tried to define the map manually but when I'm doing bulk index, It automatically maps the other fields.

ex. my JSON data looks like this

```
[
 {
    "id": "232",
    "name": "Lorem",
    "description": "Ipsum Dolor",
    "image": [
             {"key": "asadasd.jpg"},
             {"key": "asasd2d.jpg"}
    ],
    "is_active": true
 },
 ...
```

My map when I'm defining it manually

```
PUT myindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "text },
                "name": { "type": "text"},
                "description": { "type": "text" },
                "is_active": { "type": "boolean" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is the data still remain I just want to exclude the image property to be not included in the indexing.

So that When I query in the elastic search is still I get the data with image

Is that possible?

Thank you guys. I'm new in elasticsearch

```
{
    "id": "232",
    "name": "Lorem",
    "description": "Ipsum Dolor",
    "image": [
             {"key": "asadasd.jpg"},
             {"key": "asasd2d.jpg"}
    ],
    "is_active": true
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's possible simply by adding [`dynamic: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html) to your mapping, like this:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "dynamic": false,            <-- add this line
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "is_active": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `image` array will still be in the source, but the mapping won't be modified.

Comment: Does it work only on object fields like [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)? In the documentation example, `user` is an object who has `property` object and `social network` object. And `property` object can add new fields but that will not be indexed or stored as top level `dynamic` attribute is` false`. But it is not the case for `social network` object where top level `dynamic` attribute is redefined as `true`

Comment: Yes, it only works on object fields and an inner object field can override the inherited setting from the parent.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the accepted answer is, that you need to explicitly add mappings for all fields, which is not always wanted (e.g. for array types).
You could disable the field like this:

```
PUT myindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "text },
                "name": { "type": "text"},
                "description": { "type": "text" },
                "is_active": { "type": "boolean" },
                "image": { "type": "object, "enabled": false }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `image` array is still going to be in the _source.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html

Comment: I think this makes sense. But what if I have a non top-level field to disable? I think enabled can only be applied to the top-level field according to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)?